# Angular2 Http protocol might not be posting properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-http

So here's my http code:

```
    let headers = new Headers ({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
    if (body == null)
    {   
        body = {title: "hi", search: "person"};
    }   
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(body));

    return this.http.post('app/php/check.php', body, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.text())
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

I'm unsure if the server is receiving the data correctly but I am sure that it's posting something as I can see:

```
[
  {
    "select": "title",
    "search": "person"
  }
]
```

with firebug.

In my php file all I'm doing is `print_r($_REQUEST)`, however all it returns is an empty array.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Bonus question: 
Are there any other data extraction functions apart from `.json()` and `.text()` for responses?

Update:

Interestingly, if I use the url `app/php/check.php?fruit=apple` there is a response. Anyone know the discrepancy?

Comment: Are you returning a response from `check.php`, or just printing the request?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy just printing. That's how you receive responses from a php script no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server should be receiving the data that's in your body variable.

Here is an example of how you should be retrieving the output from your function. The example is using a JSON output though due to the test API I'm using for the post data. A string will be the same just change the return section.

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.postRquest().then(results => this.response = results);
}

postRquest(body) {
    let headers = new Headers ({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }); 
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
    if (body == null)
    {   
        body = {title: "hi", search: "person"};
    }   
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(body));

    return this.http.post('app/php/check.php', body, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => return response.json())
        .catch(error => {
          console.log( error );
        });
  }
```

**Make sure your content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

Plunker example:
https://embed.plnkr.co/UDYDp0gXx5H9OhmMKicL/

Comment: my code doesn't look any different to yours... and yet when I just `echo 'hi';` it gives me a return, so it's just not receiving the posts or something. Oh well, I'll keep trying stuff.

Comment: When I use $.ajax I definitely retrieve the data back

Comment: Can you open developer tools and look at the network tab and see what is returned for that Ajax request from http.

Comment: So from firebug lite (chrome) I can see that it posts the data as expected. However, the response is just an empty array.

Comment: Ok so a php problem with the response? What happens if you just try the url directly in your browser with lets say a get value app/php/check.php?test=string

Comment: prints properly: `Array ( [test] => string ) `

Comment: Have you ever used the postman browser plugin for API testing? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/introduction It can be useful for debugging and testing API calls. Just want to see if that works and it's a http problem.

Comment: what should I do with it?

Comment: You can enter the URL and set it to post and click the body tab and try to see if post data is working with your API correctly it will return below a browser window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130567/discussion-between-a-lau-and-j-j-b).